# What is a good book that serves well as an introduction to the study of differential equations?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a good book that serves well as an introduction to the study of differential equations. I don't want it to be about applications since I'm currently not particularly interested in anything but pure mathematics. I want topics like existence, uniqueness, Laplace transformation, solutions in terms of power series and moderately difficult non-linear equations to be covered rigorously. I want many assignments as well. A bonus would be if Fourier series and simple partial differential equations are covered but this is not mandatory. Preferably I would like the price to not exceed \$$100$. If there is a free pdf that would be wonderful.

Not a duplicate since I am more specific with what I want.

Comment: No, I have already checked that one and it does not include my specifications.

Comment: You might want to peruse: Differential Equations 3rd Edition by Shepley L. Ross (800-page one) , ODEs and Dynamical Systems by Teschl, ODEs by V.I. Arnold, but tough request.

Comment: I agree with @Moo. Teschl is a good choice, he has an online copy of his book. https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf

Comment: For a good introduction to ODE:http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx ; For a good introduction to PDE: Farlow: Partial Differential equations for scientists and engineers.

Comment: @Moo thank you very much.